# MQTT paho client Connection timeout error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt

I am running MQTT Mosquitto broker on my laptop. Then I am trying to connect 2 Paho MQTT clients to it: 1) From Android phone using Java Paho and 2) From Raspberry Pi using Python Paho.

From Android connection is made perfectly. No problems.

However, Raspberry for some reason can not connect. Instead the client.connect method blocks and after some time I receive the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sensorsClient.py", line 28, in <module>
    client.connect(mqttServer, 1883)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 700, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 822, in reconnect
    sock = socket.create_connection((self._host, self._port), source_address=(self._bind_address, 0))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

The code for the connection is below:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe("$SYS/#")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

mqttServer = 'zzz.xxx.ccc.qqq' # Public IP of the laptop


client = mqtt.Client("", True, None, mqtt.MQTTv31)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect(mqttServer, 1883)
client.loop_start()
```

Everythin is done within one network via WIFI. No mobile data. Can somebody please explain me why that might happen?

Comment: Can you include the rest of the code for the app so we can see  all of it please. Have you checked that you can ping the laptop from the pi and the `mqttServer` variable is the correct hostname/ip address (with no extra white space)

Comment: @hardillb I can ping with my laptop. mqttServer is a String with the IP in standard 'xxx.zzz.qqq.ttt' format (checked it several times). Won't post it, since privacy :)

Comment: I asked if you can ping the other way, from the Pi to the Laptop. Also please add the rest of the code, you can replace the IP address if you want (but assuming it's a 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x address it will be only accessible from your local network)

Comment: @hardillb I can ping in both directions

Comment: Is everything on the same network or is the phone accessing the broker via public a IP address over the cell network from the "outside"?

Comment: @hardillb One network. Wifi communication. No mobile data

Comment: What do you mean by "public IP of the laptop"? This implies your laptop is directly connected to the internet, i.e. without a router - is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

One of the first checks you can run, is go through your broker configuration (if it your own broker, otherwise ask your vendor for the credentials), and look if you have set any username/password for connection or not. Most probably that is the issue with your connection timeouts on client.

If that IS the case you just need to set username/password in your client configuration like:

`client.username_pw_set("username_on_broker", "password_on_broker")`

Also I would suggest use `urlparse.urlparse("broker url")` to sanitize/standardize your broker URL

Do reach out in case this doesn't help you.